# AspectJ ITDs: implementing a generic interface

Tags: java, generics, aspectj

I want my class to implement an interface, but I want to provide the implementation of the methods using ITD in an aspect. **Is this possible?**

Interface:

```
public interface CloningService<T> {
    public T clone(T object);
}
```

Default implementation:

```
public class DefaultCloningServiceImpl implements CloningService<T> {
    public T clone(T object) {
        // implementation of the clone method
    }
}
```

Specific implementation:

```
public class PersonService implements CloningService<Person> {
    // no code (!)
}
```

The class PersonService would declare that it implements the CloningService interface, but the actual implementation of the methods would be provided in DefaultCloningServiceImpl and an aspect would introduce them to PersonService.

I followed the example on Eclipse.com and I tried to use @DeclareParents to achieve the above functionality. However, I was getting a compiler error from AspectJ, which had to do with generics. It's as if the @DeclareParents annotation did not expect the generics to be used...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use code style aspectj to solve this rather than annotation style.

This could be done simply by having an aspect like this:

```
aspect CloningServiceAspect {
  declare parents : PersonService extends DefaultCloningServiceImpl<Object>;
}
```

To make this more general and attached to an annotation, you can do something like this:

```
aspect CloningServiceAspect {
  declare parents : (@CloningService *) extends DefaultCloningServiceImpl<Object>;
}
```

And if you wanted to package this up into a standalone jar, just make sure to add all code that you want to weave adds this jar to its aspect path (if using compile-time weaving).

Comment: Andrew, thank you for your answer. This sounds like a good idea, but I have two questions: (1) isn't annotation style aspectj preferred? my imporession was that it was the best practice. (2) the code you offered extends PersonService, but i want to extend all services marked by an annotation (or however, really), because i want to put this logic into a separate JAR. is there a solution, which would work better for me?

Comment: No, annotation style is not preferred.  For one reason, the tools do not work as well with annotation style.  Also, there are things that simply can't be done with annotation style (eg- intertype declarations).  The main reason that people choose annotation style over code style is that they want their code to be compilable by a standard Java compiler (and then they run the weaver over it).

Comment: Expanded my answer above to more fully answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! It involves using the @DeclareMixin annotation from AspectJ to mix the default implementation of the clone() method:

```
@Aspect
public class CloningServiceAspect {
    @DeclareMixin(value = "(@CloningService *)")
    public static CloningService<?> createImplementation() {
        return new DefaultCloningServiceImpl<Object>();
    }
}
```

And then my service is annotated with @CloningService instead of implementing the interface:

```
@CloningService
public class PersonService {
    // no code
}
```